# Quantifying the unique number of records using fuzzy matching

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently inner joining a customer table using the mds.mdq.similarity function in SQL Server to fuzzy match the customer name records:

```
Select a.CUST_ID as a_CUST_ID
    ,a.CU_NAME as a_CU_NAME
    ,b.CUST_ID as b_CUST_ID
    ,b.CU_NAME as b_CU_NAME
    from #tmp a
    inner join #tmp b 
    on a.CUST_ID > b.CUST_ID
        and (mds.mdq.Similarity (a.CU_NAME, b.CU_NAME, 2, 0, 0)) > 0.9
```

Now, running this query gives me the following sample table:

```
a_CUST_ID   a_CU_NAME   b_CUST_ID   b_CU_NAME
112         abc         111         abbc
113         abc-        111         abbc
111         abbc        110         abc_
112         abc         110         abc_
114         xyz         115         xyz-
```

What I would like to find is a way to quantify the number of "unique" CU_NAMEs from this ("unique" being as per the mds.mdq.similarity matching logic).

In the above sample, we would say 110 ~ 111 ~ 112 ~ 113 and 114 ~ 115. Hence, there would be 2 "unique" CU_NAMEs. The expected outcome would be:

```
Number_of_Unique_CU_NAME
2
```

Comment: Please include your expected output.

Comment: You might give [SOUNDEX()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/soundex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) a try...

Comment: @SQLUser . . . For your simple example, this works.  But you can have a series of names such as "abcd", "abce", "abfe", "agfe", and "hgfe" where pairs are connected by similarity but the overall group contains totally disparate values.